# Add info to Dock/Menubar from Shell in macOSX

Tags: macos, bash, command-line, menu-bar

I'm working on MacOSX environnement, but I would like to tweak it a bit.
I have a few bash scripts I used in Linux to retrieve infos such as IP, average ping and so, that I would like to be displayed in a persistant place. (I.E. the doc, or the menu bar).

I did not found any documentation on this topic, can someone provide a few link or the name of the correct man page to read about that?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dock and menu bar are both for use by applications only. Dock icons are managed by the [`NSDockTile`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSDockTile_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, and items on the right side of the menu bar are managed by [`NSStatusItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSStatusItem). If you want to display this information in one of those places, you'll have to create an application to do so. (If you can't convert your bash scripts to C/Obj-C, you can use [`NSTask`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/) to run them.)

Comment: I could have converted them to Obj-C, but hadn't because I wanted to keep most of my script compatible with a classic Linux/UNIX environnement. I hoped that there were a hook somewhere to acces them through SHELL.

Answer (score 5):

I just found this: https://github.com/stretchr/bitbar.
Works like a charm.

Comment: Now https://github.com/matryer/xbar

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but so too is the tool Scripts in Mac. Simply allow it to be in your menu bar. You can run scripts from there (there are various settings). For example, create a computer scripts folder called User Scripts and save all of your shell scripts there.

Answer (score -4):

How about a small tool: shellwrangler? - http://shellwrangler.com

Comment: I haven't tried this tool yet, but it looks useful, and like it would fit the asker's requirements just fine.  Why all the downvotes?  Is it secretly terrible?

Comment: Hmm... Jonathon Livingston only has two posts, and they're both linked to shellwrangler.  That's kind of weird.

Comment: Downvotes most likely are from competitors in this particular area. In terms of posts: you’re right, not much is there as I was advertising it to public. Shellwrangler is totally free as I made if for my self because I was not able to find similar tool at that time.

Comment: The link is down and redirects to ads.